# Find back the status indicator for Titanium Backup

Tags: titanium-backup

I started a time-y backup task in TB. There's a popup window showing an overall progress and which app it's currently backing up. I accidentally tapped the screen (not the Cancel button) and it disappeared. I tried to start another task and it shows "An operation is already in progress". I have no way to know how much the previous task has done.

How to I retrieve the current progress?

Comment: Is there any notification of how much it completed shown?

Comment: Have you checked in the notification area?